# Tengo un menu desplegable simple y cuando das click en el body no se regresa

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Mi duda es como hago para cuando tocas en la pagina o deslizas hacia abajo el menú se regrese, me imagino que con javascript pero tengo mínimo conocimiento. Dejo el código muchas gracias.

[Codigo completo en GitHub](https://github.com/SantiPasqua/estoadelaria.git)

Comment: Como sugerencia, en lugar de publicar todo tu código te recomiendo seguir los principios para elaborar un ejemplo mínimo https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

noté que tú ya tienes las dependencias necesarias para hacer lo siguiente sin las necesidad de utilizar Javascript. Solo copia el código de abajo.

Asegurate de tener las libresías: Jquery, popper.js y bootstrap.js

Espero sea de ayuda.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```